# is this an SQL injection

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection

In the apache access logs I found the following code as query string (GET), submitted multiple times each second for quite a while from one IP:

```
**/OR/**/ASCII(SUBSTRING((SELECT/**/COALESCE(CAST(LENGTH(rn)/**/AS/**/VARCHAR(10000))::text,(CHR(32)))/**/FROM/**/"public".belegtable/**/ORDER/**/BY/**/lv/**/OFFSET/**/1492/**/LIMIT/**/1)::text/**/FROM/**/1/**/FOR/**/1))>9
```

What does it mean?
Is this an attempt of breaking in via injection?

I have never seen such a statement and I don't understand its meaning. PostgreSQL is used on the server.
`rn` and `belegtable` exist. Some other attempts contain other existing fields/tables. Since the application is very costum, I don't know how the information on existing SQL fields can be known to strangers. Very weird.

Comment: Yes, this looks very much like an (attempted) SQL injection. The comments (`/**/`) substitute whitespaces which might not get through your filtering.

Comment: That the attacker uses table/attribute names that he should not know about is concerning. I'd suggest to block this IP and hire a security specialist.

Comment: If you can show us the code where the query string is used, we might be able to tell you whether the SQL injection was successful or not.

Comment: thanks @Bergi ! I already blocked the IP and told the programmer about the issue, also about the known table names that acutally should not be known to strangers indeed.

Comment: @meistermuh if the tables exist, you should be worried - either some hackers managed to find out what the database looks like and is trying to extract data from it, or someone created a *very* sloppy client application (SPA perhaps?) that sends SQL fragments to the API server. Something that would also enable hackers to inject SQL queries in the URL

Comment: "I don't know how the information on existing SQL fields can be known to strangers."  Maybe it is an *inside* job, from someone who knows the code but doesn't have access to the database (anymore).  Or maybe your app leaks information to a careful observer.

Answer (score 0):

```
**/
OR ASCII(
        SUBSTRING(
                    (   SELECT  COALESCE(
                                            CAST(LENGTH(rn) AS VARCHAR(10000))::text,
                                            (CHR(32))
                                        )
                        FROM    "public".belegtable 
                        ORDER BY lv 
                        OFFSET 1492 
                        LIMIT 1
                    )::text
                    FROM 1 
                    FOR 1
                  )
        ) > 9
```

> Is this an attempt of breaking in via injection?

The query in question does not have too many characteristics of an attempted SQL injection.
An SQL injection typically involves inserting an unwanted action into some section of a bigger query, under the disguise of a single value. Typically the injected part tries to guess what comes before it, neutralise it, do something malicious and secure the entire query from syntax errors by also neutralising what comes after the injected piece, which might not be visible to the attacker.

I don't see anything that could work as an escape sequence at the beginning or anything that would neutralise the remains of the query coming in after the injection. What this query does also isn't malicious. An SQL injection would attempt to extract some additional information about the database security, structure and configuration, or - if the attacker already gathered enough data - it would try to steal the data, encrypt it or tamper with it otherwise, depending on the aim and strategy of the attacker as well as the type of data found in the database. There also wouldn't be much point looping it like that.

As to the looping part: if someone attempted to put load on the database - as in [DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) - you'd likely see more than one node doing that and probably in a more elaborate and well disguised manner, using different and more demanding queries sent at different frequencies.

> What does it mean?

It's likely someone's buggy code stuck in an unterminated loop, judging by the [LIMIT and OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-limit.html) mechanism I've seen used for looping through some set of records by taking one at a time (LIMIT 1) and incrementing which one to get next (OFFSET n). The whole expression always returns **true** because [ASCII()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) returns the character code of the first character in the string. That string defaults to a space ' ', ASCII code 32, or some text representation of a number between 0 and 99999. Sice all ASCII digits are between code 48 and 57, it's effectively always comparing some bigger number than 9 to a 9, checking if it indeed is bigger.

The author of that code might not have predicted the loop to be able to run infinitely and might have misinterpreted what some of the functions used in that query do. Regardless of what really happened, I think it was a good idea to cut off that IP avoiding needless stress on the database. Double-checking your security setup is always a good idea but I wouldn't call this an attempted attack. At least not this query alone, as it might be a harmless piece of a bigger, more malicious operation - but that could be said about any query.

Comment: That assumes there are arbitrary authors out there who can run such code. Also, if legit, why would the code be doing such seemingly strange things in such an elaborate way? Granted, I don't know much about PostGreSQL specifically, but that looks to me like perhaps a bunch of attempts to detect known security flaws existent in older versions, and/or to leak some piece of info about the data in the table (such as length or order).

Comment: I agree. Your question does not specify that but if this IP is unwelcome running arbitrary code - and/or is not even expected to be able to - a security check is recommended. In my post I focused on answering your question, which was about that specific query being an SQL injection attempt or not, as well as about what that query does. I don't think it's an SQL injection, which is not to say one did not succeed before or after this query. As to why the code does what it does - it's looks like a part of something bigger, a buggy part, so I can't conclude much from it.

Comment: It's not my question. I just find it very difficult to believe anyone would write such obtuse, obfuscated code for any well-intentioned purpose.

Comment: This is either a partially successful injection attack or some very bad client-side (SPA?) code that would allow a SQL injection attack. Unfortunately, there are a ton of bad SO questions and answers showing such vulnerabilities.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have seen a lot of copied/pasted rubbish on here but must have been lucky in having not seen any SQL as bad as this until now ;-)

Comment: What it does might seem strange and elaborate mostly due to the weird formatting, the entire thing being one long line with whitespaces replaced by blank comments. Once properly formatted it loses that strange look. The author most likely did not type it that way, it's rather a result of the library handling the connection. I also agree with @PanagiotisKanavos - whoever made this might not have understood their own code themselves in the first place. Plus, this indeed might be a piece of a bigger whole involving an SQL injection or other malicious activity.

Comment: I've also seen "put an HTTP API in front of the database because potatoes at REST". This could be a paging query sent by an SPA to such an "HTTP database adapter".

Comment: thanks for the code explanation, @Zegarek. I was very confused by all the `/**/` at first 'cause I didn't recognize this as an empty comment. And you're right: this statement is always true and might lead to some infinite loop. It, however, doesn't seem to be a code present on the server since none of the files contain `COALESCE` or some other parts of that code. Atacking the server via infinite statements that crash it, on the other hand, would be much easier by a shorter one. Still weird...

Comment: That infinite loop would be on the client side. It's the client that according to my guess would keep increasing the `OFFSET` argument for each query sent to the database. Those queries would come independently one by one, from a loop in the client. The loop and the query itself being a pretty dubious attack strategy was exactly my point. Regardless of whether the author was just incompetent or incompetent **and** malicious, you do need to watch out for them.

Comment: There are guides on PostgreSQL hardening that could help you adjust built-in settings to secure whatever you expect to be the main threat, if securing the point where these queries come from by sanitising its inputs is beyond your reach. You could also try and look in the logs for the remaining part of that query, as it seems incomplete on its own - context might provide you some more answers.
I wonder if this could be someone from the inside forced to work from home without means or skill to communicate with the db otherwise but with full knowledge of the structure they deal with :)

Comment: @Zegarek we might not find out who and why but we will prevent it in the future by hardening things. It's impossible that someone from the inside did this, since the users all are laypeople in respects of IT and the one and only, trustworthy programmer actually can't have any intention to do such.